# Получить сумму чисел

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В JS написать программу, где пользователь будет вводить любое количество цифр через пробел и видеть их сумму через input.
Без input то не сложно, а с ним ни как понять не могу, как с пробелами считать

Comment: Покажи как тебе "несложно" без инпут... Останется это только "связать" с кнопкой и инпутом. ;)

Comment: а как сделать, что бы инпут понимал пробел в числах?

Comment: Обычный `<input type='text' />` все нормально "понимает". Как числа, так и пробелы...

Comment: а, спасибо, не знал )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать `.split(separator)`:

```js
function getSum() {
  document
    .getElementById("result")
    .innerText = document
      .getElementById("numbers")
      .value
      .split(" ")
      .map(x => parseInt(x))
      
      .reduce((x, y) => x + y);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numbers" value="1 45 7 8 22"></input><br/>
<button onclick="getSum();">Get sum</button><br/>
<a id="result"></a>
```

UPD: В комментариях подметили про NaN:

```js
function getSum() {
  document
    .getElementById("result")
    .innerText = document
      .getElementById("numbers")
      .value
      .split(" ")
      .map(x => {
        const y = parseInt(x);
        return isFinite(y)
          ? y
          : 0;
      })
      .reduce((x, y) => x + y);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numbers" value="1 45 7 8 22"></input><br/>
<button onclick="getSum();">Get sum</button><br/>
<a id="result"></a>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, я тебя не забуду старче :D

Comment: если ввод заканчивается на пробел, то получается NaN. А если в вводе есть буква, то результат зависит от того, где эта буква расположена

Comment: Два пробела подряд -> `NaN`.

Answer (score 2):

Предложу еще такой вариант...

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', _ => {
  result.textContent = numbers.value.match(/\d+/g).reduce((s, v) => s + +v, 0)
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numbers" value="1 45 7 8 22"></input><br/>
<button>Get sum</button><br/>
<p id="result"></p>
```